# How to flatten tables correcty in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery, flatten

I have the following tables:

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

In table 2 (yellow looking fields), the first field is part of the following:

```
name1                       RECORD      NULLABLE    
name1. name2                RECORD      REPEATED    
name1.name2. date_inserted  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

As you can see the last (sub-row?) of the row 25 is greyed because it is part of the repeated record name1.name2

I am trying to join table 2, with table 1(orange looking fields) on another field. I have 0 experience with records or repeated records but using FLATTEN() I managed to join them.

The problem is, I noticed that some dates from the 2nd after the join return NULL although there aren't any NULLS before it. So since I can't figure out what the greyed cells are I guess I am doing something wrong.

All this sums up to: How can I totally flatten all tables that I want to use so that there won't be any records at all and so I can go through the data with simple SQL statements? Please provide an example as well. Looking for something generic.

Comment: What did you do so far ? Were the examples in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated#flatten) not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I totally flatten all tables that I want to use so that there won't be any records at all and so I can go through the data with simple SQL statements?

It really depends on the schemas you are working with. You can preprocess them, flatten the arrays and rename the structs fields, then use that as your base table to work with simple SQL statements

For your scenario, you can start by flattening the table 2, name2 column like this

```sql
SELECT
  name2.date_inserted -- Add additional fields you want on the result
FROM table2, table2.name1.name2
```

You can do CROSS JOIN and LEFT JOIN to further adjust your results.

> Please provide an example as well. Looking for something generic.

I'm not sure about a generic approach, since each schema would probably have distinct requirements. The key concept is to know how to [flatten arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) and how to query [struct with arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-array-type-fields-in-a-struct) and [arrays of structs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-struct-elements-in-an-array)

You can find plenty examples in that documentation